# Kingston USB flash drive formatting problem !

Tags: windows-xp, usb, formatting, usb-flash-drive, partition-magic

My 2GB kingston flash drive is not being formatted in windows XP OS !!

When I try to format it, it doesn't get formatted through windows standard formatting option or even in Partition magic 8.0 (DOS based version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **[HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=197)** (it works for all USB storage devices).

[image]

*This tool is particularly handy if you want to format large HDDs using the FAT32 file system or if you want to create a bootable USB drive.*

Answer (score 1):

If your flash drive isn't formatting, that's a good indication it's died/close to dying. I'd highly reccomend getting a new one, and copying all the data from your current one. USB drives aren't worth repairing, IMO, and are certainly inexpensive enough (Although it's awful environmentally - is there any way you can re-purpose it?)

Comment: unfortunately dead hardware is dead hardware.  unless you want to repurpose it into a homemade christmas ornament (or something else purely decorative) -- or you're interested in disassembling the thing to pull out & test the components -- i don't see repurposing as very realistic.

Comment: I meant as ornamental stuff, unfortunately, yeah. Not much one can do with a dead USB stick, unfortunately :( (I have about 4 dead ones in a box)

Comment: well, if you really wanted to, you *could* extract the PCB and figure out what failed.  mem controller? USB bridge? or the memory chips themselves?  more than likely *something* is still good.  but yeah, unless you're *really* into that sort of thing, it's just not practical.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try formatting on another machine which have different OS.My USB made the same in the past and I could format it on my friend's laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your flash drive is broken. If it's not very old, maybe you can get it swapped where you bought it?

That said, maybe there's another thing you can try:
Do you see the flash drive in Windows Disk Management (My computer -> right click -> Manage -> Storage -> Disk Management)?
If so, what happens if you format it from there? Or otherwise remove and re-create the partition?